# Custom Component for DropShadow

Tags: qt, qml, custom-component, dropshadow

Since these properties of `DropShadow` don't change:

```
radius: 10
samples: 15
color: "black"
```

in my usage, I tried to create a Custom Component named `Shadow.qml` that sets these:

```
anchors.fill: target
source: target
```

two properties. Here it is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

DropShadow{
    id: root
    /*
    property string target
    anchors.fill: target
    source: target
    */

    //property alias target: root.anchors.fill | root.source

    /*
    property alias fill: root.anchors.fill
    property alias source: root.source
    */

    radius: 10
    samples: 15
    color: "black"
}
```

and in my usage, I can use it like this:

```
Shadow{
    anchors.fill: myTarget
    source: myTarget
}
```

and it works. The problem is I've to write `myTarget` in two places (i.e. `anchors.fill` and `source`) so I want to reduce it to a single line like this `Shadow{ target: myTarget }`

I've tried with each of those 3 commented out parts of `Shadow.qml` and none of those work!

Comment: First commented out line `property string target` should be `Item` probably? I don't have a running Qt installation here, but You can try `DropShadow {  anchors.fill: source; property alias target: source; ... }`

Comment: @derM, up until now I've always used it only on `Rectangle`. Will it work on `Item` as well?

Comment: Usually, GraphicalEffects work on any visual `Item` applying a shader to the non-transparent pixel. Documentation is strange, declaring the type of `source` to be `alias` - when I worked with Qt, that was not a type... But that was with Qt 5.9

Comment: @derM, yes `Rectangle/Item` instead to string works, great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Target should not be a `string` it should be the Object on which the DropShadow should be applied to, which can be any kind of graphical `Item`

```
property Item target
anchors.fill: target
source: target
```

should work.
However you can also just make it fill the source:

```
anchors.fill: source
```

now, instead of setting the target, you set the Source:

```
Shadow {
    source: Rectangle { ... }
}
```

If the property name `target` is required, create an alias for source:

```
DropShadow {
    property alias target: source
    anchors.fill: source
    ...
}
```

Creating an alias instead of a *real* property should be more efficient.

Comment: I'll use your second approach, no property at all, just set the source of `Shadow`